# How to show two views per rows in scollview in React native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

How to show two views per rows in scollview in React native?
It is difficult to change the large framework since I made a view by pulling the json with module.
I would like to show views in the scrollview in the form shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx6EL.png) <-- image link

I’d be glad if you could help me. 
** If it have no idea in current method, you can give me a new idea.

this is code (const styles skipped)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, StatusBar, FlatList, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import logoImg from '../../images/logo.png';
import SearchInput, { createFilter } from 'react-native-search-filter';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Icon2 from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import promotion_list from '../../data/market_list.js';
const KEYS_TO_FILTERS = ['name', 'subject'];
const myIcon = (<Icon name="times" size={25} color='#949494' />)

export default class Market extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: ''
    }
  }
  searchUpdated(term) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
  }

  render() {
    const filteredlists = promotion_list.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))
    return (
      <View style={styles.SearchList}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', margin: 10, padding: 10, height: 40, borderRadius: 100, backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }}>
          <Icon name="search" size={20} color='#949494' style={{ flex: 0, marginRight: 10 }} />
          <SearchInput
            clearIcon={myIcon}
            clearIconViewStyles={{ position: 'absolute', right: 6 }}
            onChangeText={(term) => { this.searchUpdated(term) }}
            placeholder="Search"
            inputViewStyles={{ flex: 1 }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Image style={{width:390, height:180}} source={require("../../images/market/topview.png")} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={{marginLeft:15, marginTop:10, marginBottom:10, fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:20, color: '#494a51'}}>Your Partners</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.ScrollView}>
          {filteredlists.map(plist => {
            function getImage(img_name) {
              switch (img_name) {
                case "1.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/1.png");
                case "2.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/2.png");
                case "3.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/3.png");
                case "4.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/4.png");
                case "5.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/5.png");
                case "6.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/6.png");
                case "7.png": return require("../../images/par_logo/7.png");
                case "p1.png": return require("../../images/promotion_feed/1.png");
                case "p2.png": return require("../../images/promotion_feed/2.png");
                case "p3.png": return require("../../images/promotion_feed/3.png");
                case "p4.png": return require("../../images/promotion_feed/4.png");
                case "p5.png": return require("../../images/promotion_feed/5.png");
              }
            }
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} key={plist.id} style={styles.ListItem}>

                  <View style={{ paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, height: 50, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Image style={{ marginRight: 10, width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: Image.resizeMode.contain }} source={getImage(plist.src1)} />
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{plist.name}</Text>
                  </View>

                  <View style={{margin:0}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { alert("you clicked me") }}>
                      <Image style={{}} source={getImage(plist.src2)} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a FlatList which is inherited from ScrollView and use the numColumns prop. [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)